# Modify a FeatureManager value in a SpecFlow test

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, specflow

I have a Controller where a `FeatureManager` is injected and the code branches depending on the values read from `_featureManager.IsEnabledAsync("NameOfFeature")`. I am using *SpecFlow* and want to create a `Given` attribute that modifies a particular FeatureManager feature so I can test with the feature enabled and disabled.

At the same time, I would like to control some of the features from the environment (e.g. set them in appsettings.json) because they will change depending on how the tests are executed (locally or in docker in a CI-pipeleine). This is an ASP.NET Core application set up with dependency injection.

The appsettings.json file contains features in section "FeatureManagement". The features that are used by the application projects can be mocked, they don't have to be read from this file, but some features are to be used by the SpecFlow project and have to be taken from this file.

**Question**

How can I control what the `IFeatureManager` returns in the tests while also reading some other features from appsettings.json? It is acceptable to mock the FeatureManager, as well as defining a custom one.

**Code**

Hooks.cs (SpecFlow project)

```cs
[Binding]
public sealed class Hooks
{
    private static IHost _host;

    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void BeforeTestRun()
    {
        // Program is the app being tested. It contains a Startup class with 
        // services.AddFeatureManagement(configuration.GetSection("FeatureManagement"));
        var hostBuilder = Program.CreateHostBuilder(Array.Empty<string>());

        hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) => {
           // Test services that we wish to inject in the app are added here
        });

        _host = hostBuilder.Build();
        _host.Start();
    }

    [ScenarioDependencies]
    public static IServiceCollection CreateServices()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        
        // Services that are injected in the SpecFlow step definitions are added here
        services.AddFeatureManagement(configuration.GetSection("FeatureManagement"));

        return services;
    }
}
```

StepDefinitions.cs (SpecFlow project)

```
    [Given(@"the feature '([^']*)' is enabled")]
    public void GivenTheFeatureIsEnabled(string feature)
    {
        // Set up the FeatureManager to return true for the feature
    }

    // And similar for when the feature is disabled
```

Startup.cs (Application) Simplified for brevity

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddFeatureManagement(_configuration.GetSection("FeatureManagement"));
        // Other services added...
    }
}
```

Comment: I keep coming back to this question, but I really have no idea where to begin. Can you [edit] your question to include more code? I'm honestly not sure what code to include. I'm not clear how to recommend a fix. Are you spinning up a web application?

Comment: Thank you! I added some clarifications and removed the requirement of not mocking the FeatureManager.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically enable or disable feature toggles while running tests?

Comment: It feels like the IFeatureManager used in the application needs to be the same exact object instance used by SpecFlow. To be honest, I would create your own implementation of that interface for use in the application and the tests, and then use some other default implementation when the app is deployed.